# Vue array not Updating

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a jquery click function on a table row that takes the value of the table row and puts it into a list i then set the list equal to the vue array i have here are the arrays.
Array:

```
 tableRow: [
                {
                    "name": "1",
                    "numSongs": "2",
                    "Year": "3"
                }
            ]
```

Function:

```
    $("#table1 tr").click(function () {
        var list = [];

        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
            $tds = $row.find("td");

        list.push({ name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() });
        this.tableRow =  list;
        console.log(this.tableRow);
    });
```

I also log the value of the list when the app loads and when i click it and it does change.
[image: console output]

Then i have a function to test if the values have changed just a simple alert function.

```
greet: function () {
            // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
            alert('Hello ' + this.tableRow[0].name )
        },
```

But the value doesn't update in the function does anyone know why.

Vue Instance Code

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            tableRow: [
                {
                    "name": "1",
                    "numSongs": "2",
                    "Year": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log(this.tableRow);
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            $("#table1 tr").click(function () {
                var list = [];

                var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
                    $tds = $row.find("td");

                list.push({ name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() });
                this.tableRow =  list;
                console.log(this.tableRow);
            });
        });
    },

    methods: {
        greet: function () {
            // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
            alert('Hello ' + this.tableRow[0].name )
        },
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the vue instance code

Comment: I've added it to the question just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the scoping issue of `this`

In your click handler you are doing `this.tableRow = list` where `tableRow` is a property of data option in the vue instance **but** `this` **is not pointing to the vue instance**, it refers to element which invoked the event

So do it like this:

```
mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.tableRow);
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        $("#table1 tr").click(function () {
            var list = [];

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
                $tds = $row.find("td");

                list.push({ name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() });
                self.tableRow =  list;
                console.log(this.tableRow);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: @DanielM96 happy to help :)